# How do you turn off the auto search/find when using the search tool in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm working with a large script within Rstudio and I need to change the name of certain objects using the find and replace options (accessed through the magnifying glass symbol at the top of the script editing window).

When I'm trying to rename an object in only a small part of the script (using the 'in selection' tick box), after entering the object name in the 'find' box, the script window will jump to the first occurrence of the object and I lose my place with the section I was editing. It's very **frustrating**. Does anyone know how to turn this off? Or a way to avoid it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work in the following order:

1. Enter the object name (Do not copy paste).
2. Highlight the desired text.
3. Tick the "In selection" box.

If you work in this order, you should not encounter your above described problem.

Comment: I think it may have stemmed from copying and pasting the object name into the search box. If I: Highlight the object - then copy and paste the object to the search box - the auto search issue still happens.

Comment: Does the above described method work for you? If so, can you highlight it as the solution for others if they encouter the same problem.